# Spectral threshold effect: examples

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, sp.spectral-theory

I know that the effect of homogenization can be treated as a spectral threshold effect. I want to know more examples of spectral threshold effects in mathematical physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overview of threshold effects on a band structure is given by Birman and Suslina, in their paper on [Second order periodic differential operators](https://www.ams.org/journals/spmj/2004-15-05/S1061-0022-04-00827-1/S1061-0022-04-00827-1.pdf) (2004). Generically, this refers to cases where it suffices to know the approximate spectral expansion of the initial differential operator near the lower edge $\lambda=0$ of the spectrum. For example, the appearance of a negative discrete spectrum when the operator is perturbed is a threshold effect. An important physical application is the construction of an "effective mass", which describes the curvature of the band structure near the edge.